# Reduce unable to solve simple inequalities with quantifiers

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I have try to solve following inequalities using `Mamthematica`. But it unable to solve that.

```
Reduce[ForAll[{n}, Implies[{n, N1} >= 0 && n < N1, n < A]] && 
  N1 >= A, {N1,A}, Integers]
```

Expected Result

```
N1=A
```

If we solve that manually,it is very simple.Please Suggest . am I making any mistake or other way to handle this type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you defined the conditions is a little bit hazy to me. For example consider `{n, N1} >= 0 && n < N1`. The first condition does not do anything to `N1`. In fact,

```
Reduce[{n, N1} >= 0 && n < N1, {n, N1}]
```

> n >= 0 && N1 > n

So you can simply combine them to `N1>0`. Make this modification in your first condition, and you will get

```
Reduce[0 < N1 && 0 < A && N1 >= A, {N1, A}, Integers]
```

> (C[1] | C[2]) [Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0 && 
>    N1 == 1 + C[1] + C[2] && A == 1 + C[2]

and for `C[1]=0` you get your desired answer.